# How to approach the numerical solution of the Ermakov–Pinney equation?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, nonlinear

Suppose we have the following [non-linear differential equation](http://people.math.umass.edu/~kevrekid/math697/sdarticle_dr.pdf)

$$\displaystyle{\ddot{x}+\omega^2(t) x-\frac1{x^3}}=0,$$

where $x(t)$ is a function of time $t$ a and where we choose $\omega^2(t)$ to be some (positive) periodic function, to be more specific, let us say

$$\omega_1(1+\sin^2(\omega_2 t)),$$

with $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ being positive constants.

Let us choose $\omega_1=1$ and $\omega_2=2$, and the initial conditions e.g. $x(0)=1$, $x'(0)=1$.

How to approach the solution in *Mathematica*?

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2219030/how-to-solve-ddotx-omega2t-x-frac1x3-0-for-a-particular-form-of-o

Comment: When I searched the documentation for "differential equation" the first hit was [this guide to differential equations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DifferentialEquations.html) that points out both symbolic and numerical solvers.  What happened when you searched?

Comment: @wondering Did you saw my answer?

Comment: @zhk Yes, thank you, this answers my question. Btw., you must be from India, right? --> "Did you SEE my answer?" :-)

Comment: @wondering Close! I am grandson of Taliban supreme leader Mullah Umar. Thx for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For numerical solution to ODE's/PDE's you can use `NDSolve`. For more details visit [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html).

1.$\omega(t)$ as a triangle function

```
w[t_] = UnitTriangle[t]

ODE = x''[t] + w[t]^2*x[t] - 1/x[t]^3 == 0;

sol = NDSolve[{ODE, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, x[t], {t, -10, 10}]

Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

2.$\omega^2(t)=\omega_1(1+\sin^2(\omega_2 t))$

```
w[t_] = w1*(1 + Sin[w2*t]^2);

w1 = 1; w2 = 2;

ODE = x''[t] + w[t]*x[t] - 1/x[t]^3 == 0;

sol = NDSolve[{ODE, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, x[t], {t, -10, 10}];

Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, -10, 10}]
```

[image]